# Is it possible to customize the Jquery Data Table default generated dom structure?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I am using a Jquery Data Table Plugin found at http://datatables.net/api.  The plugin generates it's own search box, which it inserts into the page upon initialization if enabled. When a search box is created it is nested in it's own div like this:

```
<div>
    <!-- search code -->
</div>
<table>
    <!-- table data -->
</table>
```

I want to have a scroll bar on the table without moving the search box, so that it is always visible.  Overflow-y:scroll; doesn't seem to work for me on a table element but does work on a div.  Is that right?  If I apply the style to the parent container then the search box is not visible if the user scrolls down.  I tried physically moving the element myself to the desired setup which is:

```
<div>
    <!-- Search Code -->
</div>
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;"> <!-- actually in a class but this shows what it is. -->
    <table>
        <!-- table data -->
    </table>
</div>
```

As would be expected that breaks the plugin generated search box.  So my question is, can I achieve the desired outcome using the plugin's built-in search feature, perhaps using an argument like 'sdom' somehow, or do I need to bite the bullet and roll my own search/filter feature?

Comment: this might sound silly, but why not simply use the pagination element to the data tables, restrict the results to 10 or 20 per page, and then there would be no need to scroll, and it would eliminate this issue.

Comment: My client has specifically requested scrolling over paging, I've already had this discussion with them you see.  My preference would be for the paging but it isn't a case of my preference.  You made a highly valid point though but unfortunately not one that I can use in this case.

Comment: have you tried posting this question on the JQuery Datatables forum??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was just to turn off the built-in filter and write my own equivalent that I could place where ever I like.

http://jsfiddle.net/KwXby/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tableFilter").bind("change keyup", function(){
  var tableRows = $('.dataTable:visible').find('tbody').find('tr');
  var filterText = $(this).val();
  $(tableRows).each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf(filterText ) >= 0) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
  });
});
```

EDIT:
I later found that I needed to be able to search multiple columns with space separated search terms and provide an empty table row if none were found, which warranted an update.

http://jsfiddle.net/KwXby/11/